# Selective json deserialization c# and json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

I am using an API which returns JSON response. 
The issue im facing is the way they return their error messages: 
They return

```
["501","Invalid apikey"]
```

instead of the normal json response which is serialized to :

```
public class AvailableItemResponse : IResponse
{
    public AvailableItemResponse ()
    {
        AvailableItems = new List<AvailableItem>();
    }

    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string SearchId { get; set; }
    public int TotalFound { get; set; }
    public List<AvailableItem> AvailableItems { get; set; }

}
```

How can I check the json format and select which type to deserialze the object to ?

Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HttpClient there should be a Code on the object received. Would thing something like the following will help.

```
if(response.code != 200){
     //handle the error
}
```

Comment: I'm using HTTP client, but the response code is 200 even when they send errors ! This is a very nonstandard API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is that you don't have a `key-value` json. You could check for the position of the elements and if it's a fixed parameter you can look at (for example) the first parameter and compare it to the code of the `ok` message (probably always the same). In this case the `ResponseId` is 501 so you shouldn't parse the json.

So if first parameter is `STATUS_CODE_OK` parse the json otherwise not.